# Trigger on Email message related to an opportunity optimization problem

Tags: trigger, soql, emailmessage

I actually have some confusion with my code . i'm trying to create a trigger that fires when an emailMessage related to an opportunity is inserted. 
My code is fine but i was thinking that if my opportunity number is quite large i will definitely have issues with my code.  Is there any way to optimize it ?

this is my trigger code :

```
trigger DCE_TR_EmailMessage on EmailMessage (After insert) {

    if (Trigger.IsInsert){
        if (Trigger.IsAfter){
            for(EmailMessage em : Trigger.new ) {   
              //  SetId.add(em.RelatedToId);
                if (DCE_EmailMessage.isRelatedOpp(em)== true ){
                     DCE_DataFactory.createTask(1,em);
                }             
            }       
        }
    }   
}
```

---

```
public class DCE_EmailMessage {
    public static boolean isRelatedOpp(EmailMessage em){
        List<Opportunity> opps =[SELECT id  FROM Opportunity WHERE id =: em.RelatedToId];
        if (opps.size()>0 ){
            return true;
        }
        else return false;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible to use the `relatedToId` field to determine what type of object it points to *without needing a query*.

The Id class contains a `getSObjectType()` method, which returns a `Schema.SObjectType`.

You can use this directly to check if it's an opp like so

`myId.getSObjectType() == Opportunity.SObjectType`

Comment: Yes this works for me thank you

Answer (score 1):

> My code is fine but i was thinking that if my opportunity number is quite large i will definitely have issues with my code

Yes, your intuition is correct: you have at least one, and possibly two, issues related to bulkification.

```
    for(EmailMessage em : Trigger.new ) {   
        if (DCE_EmailMessage.isRelatedOpp(em)== true ){ // DANGER: runs SOQL
             DCE_DataFactory.createTask(1,em); // DANGER: probably runs DML
        }
```

Anywhere you have that structure of needing to run a query or perform a data change for each record in a collection, you need to factor the actual query or data update out of the list. You accumulate the required parameters in memory and perform a single DML operation or SOQL query *outside* the loop.

Additionally, as Derek pointed out, you don't need the SOQL at all - but you presumably still will have DML inside `createTask()`.

I strongly recommend completing the [Bulk Apex Triggers](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/apex_triggers/apex_triggers_bulk) unit on Trailhead, which teaches the correct patterns you need to achieve this type of code while staying within the Salesforce governor limits.

Comment: I will have a look at the trailhead . Thank you for your advice David